# returning a method name

Tags: php

I'm using the following as a way of seeing listing the various methods in my developement

```
print basename(__FILE__) . "::serve_table()"
```

is there any function that's able to return the name of a class method so I don't have to trpe it each time?

Answer (score 8):

Use `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` and `__CLASS__` and `__METHOD__`

Comment: The question was tagged “PHP”, though.

Comment: Yes I realized that and took the gcc reference out, but these constants work in php also.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the information provided by [`debug_backtrace`](http://de.php.net/debug_backtrace) which provides the stack trace in an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understanding if you need a way to list all the methods of a class or if you need to retrieve the method name you have just called.

If the former, using reflection:

```
$class = new ReflectionCLass("classname");
$methods = $class->getMethods();
foreach($methods as $m)
    print $m->getName();
```